# Table per Concrete Type with tables as context properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a base class for all of my tables in order to make sure I have some data like CreateDate/Person, etc on all of my data.

So basically, I want my tables to inherit from a base class, but I want to have that data on each table separably (table per concrete type).

I've found some tutorials like these, but the problem with them is that I won't have any strongly named property for my tables.

[weblogs.asp.net](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)

As you see, in the link he created a dbset of the base class and there is no relation to the concrete class.

```
public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BillingDetail> BillingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class TrackableBase 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; protected set; }

    public TrackableBase()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

}

public class User : TrackableBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a property of type DbSet for each class and add the OnModelCreating for the mapping

```
public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Users");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, that is exactly the same link that I've shared in my question! Plus, I want to have access to my tables as strongly type ones. This way I will have only 1 list in my DBContext that contains all my types!

Comment: So sorry, didn't notice that.  But you can put as many DbSet as you need without the base class, I have changed my answer to reflect that